# Excrement, faeces or poop?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, register

In daily conversation, when we discuss/say about the baby excrement/faeces.

Which word should we used? ***Excrement, faeces or poop***?

Comment: I love this site.  This is exactly the type of question that you genuinely need to know if you want to speak English, but which a language course is **never** going to teach you.

Comment: Just an aside: It's usually spelled _feces_ in American English.

Comment: The word $\ddag$ `shit` is often used in this context, but it could be considered obscene or vulgar unless talking to people you are very familiar with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In daily conversation you would say **poop** or **poo** in American English.

**Excrement** is used when talking about feces (the AmE spelling) being disgusting and filthy.

**Feces** is usually used to describe it in a more clinical or studied way, as to a doctor or scientist.

We also say that a baby has a **dirty/soiled diaper**.  You could also simply say that a baby **is dirty**, or that the baby **needs changing.**

You might also hear someone say that a baby **went number two.**  Number one would be peeing.  This is *very* informal.

For wild animals, the word **scat** is often used.

For farm animals, the word **manure** is used.

Any of these might jokingly be used to describe a baby's poop.

Comment: When dealing with dirty diapers, there's also _doo-doo_, a "baby-talk" alternative.

Comment: Also, **scat** is used when referring to a sexual nature, **fecal matter** is sometimes used in place of feces for science, and in medical context you'll often find **stool** is the term of choice. Also, among adults (or those pretending to be adult) willing to be informal, the vulgarity **shit** is used more often than any other.

Comment: Probably worth noting that **needs changed** is a regionalism; **needs changing** or **needs to be changed** would be more broadly used...

Comment: I'd like to point out (since the OP has not stated whether they prefer Brittish or American English, though has used the Brittish spelling of faeces) that **nappy** is preferred in Brittish English as opposed to diaper. Also **poop** is less common in Brittish English.

Comment: @Micah 'needs changed' is a regionalism? To me it just looks plain wrong. Never seen that usage before.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've noticed omission of "to be" in contexts like this becoming increasingly common, although I don't know of any association with a specific region. And indeed, I certainly wouldn't consider it _correct_ (although it seems that the day will come when that changes). [edited to add] http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24163

Comment: @Micah I agree that "needs changing" is grammatical and altered my answer accordingly.  I've rarely heard that version conversationally though, and I've had babies to take care of in the US South, Midwest, and East Coast.  I don't know a resource to check it properly, but a google search returns 3 times as many results for "baby needs changed" versus "baby needs changing."

Comment: @JasonPatterson I don't think that's a fair Google. If you include the quotes in the search, you're looking for a phrase that literally isn't very common; if you omit the quotes, then the search term *baby needs changed* will include "needs to be changed" as well.